# How to get the number '500' in the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
'use strict';
var arr = [[1, 2, 3], [400, 500, 600], '-'];
// ...........
alert(x); // x should be 500.
```

I tried the following code.

```
arr.pop();
arr.shift();
arr.pop();
arr.shift();
var x=arr;
```

or using splice(), but I get nothing.

Comment: Why can't you directly index it like `arr[1][1]`?

Comment: do you actually know where in the array it'll be?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way, IMHO, would be to use the subscript operator (`[]`). The second element (zero based!) in `arr` is the array containing `500`, and the second element in that array is `500` itself. So:

```
var x = arr[1][1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.pop();
arr.shift();
arr=arr[0];
arr.pop();
arr.shift();
var x=arr;
```

With the pop and shift You supplied. But You should use indexers instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can access it by arr[1][1].

Popping and shifting the elements won't do much to help you with finding 500 because your format is

```
[Array, Array, String]
```

and result in alerts telling you only that you've found that array.

If you want to programmatically find 500 with a format such as this, you can use `indexOf` on each element to find if it exists, and the index of it within the subarray.